# Iterate after ajax completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I foreach 366 jquery elements and if I find a specific class I call a function, the function either loads HTML via ajax or edits already existing one. But while iterating the function just keeps loading HTML instead of editing existing one, because the ajax takes time to load it. I tried promises but I can't tell the loop to wait and then iterate.

Basically I have

```
$('#calendars .day').each(function(index, element){
    if ($(element).hasClass('something')) {
        callAjaxFunction($(element).text(), $(element).data('id'));
    } else {
        callNoAjaxFunction($(element).attr('class'));
    }
});
```

Comment: is your ajax call asynchronous ?

Comment: Yes, I don't think async: false works in the new jQuery versions

Comment: Make it async to do not waiting for ajax to complete

Comment: I found another solution, it's ugly but it works.